# python QAxWidget is not execute

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I use QAxWidget with python.  Until yesterday, the following code run well. but now don't well. Code result is 'return 1'

```
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import *
class test(QAxWidget):  
    def __init(self):
        super.__init__()

      ......
test()
```

[image]

the following code is the same

```
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import *
a = QAxWidget()
```

So, I think that PyQt5 file breaks up. I uninstall Anaconda and install Anaconda.
But result is same.
And I run the program with python idle. Originally, pyCharm.
But result is same.

help me. What should i do? Please!!

Comment: Run the code as a script in a normal command window using e.g. `python.exe test.py`. This should show a python traceback and/or some qt warning messages.

Comment: So i run with Jupyter. And result is same. jupyter said that "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." What should i do???

Comment: I solved!!! I add code 'My_Application = QApplication(sys.argv)'   So, It's running well.   Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import os, sys


class MyMainWindow(QAxWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QAxWidget.__init__(self)

        # < Global Settings >
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello")
        self.setFixedSize(510, 510)
        self.move(400, 30)
        # </ Global Settings >


if __name__ == '__main__':

    My_Application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MyMainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(My_Application.exec_())
```

Good Luck ...

Comment: Umm, Sorry.... the result is same. So i run with Jupyter. And result is same. jupyter said that "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." What should i do???

Comment: I solved!!! I add code 'My_Application = QApplication(sys.argv)'   So, It's running well.   Thank you